# elisp data structures/workflow for constructing a list

Tags: ruby, list, emacs, lisp, elisp

```
arrayA = ["arrayA_1", "arrayA_2", "arrayA_3", "arrayA_4", "arrayA_5"]
arrayB = ["arrayB_1", "arrayB_2", "arrayB_3", "arrayB_4", "arrayB_5"]
arrayC = ["arrayC_1", "arrayC_2", "arrayC_3", "arrayC_4", "arrayC_5"]


arrayA.length.times do |x| 
  p list = [ [arrayA[x]] , [arrayB[x]] , [arrayC[x]] ]                                                                                                                           
end
```

How to replicate this simple Ruby codeblock in elisp?

Comment: see also the libraries [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and [seq.el](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el) for manipulating lists.

Comment: Awesome! i noticed them before but as I am not that experienced with elisp my instinct was to ignore the noise of the ecosystem and focus on the basics instead. but now as you mentioned them as well as did others, they seem popular enough to me, and perhaps worth the effort of divin into the rabbit hole! thanks :)

Comment: I would not use dash.el , since it has a weird calling interface.

Comment: @RainerJoswig weird how? Is seq.el different?

Comment: Just look at the code of dash.el . It's horrible. Main mistake: the implementation is done in zillions of macros. Don't. Never. Ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ELISP> (cl-mapcar 'concat
        '("firstA" "secondA" "thirdA")
        '("firstB" "secondB" "thirdB")
        '("firstC" "secondC" "thirdC"))
("firstAfirstBfirstC" "secondAsecondBsecondC" "thirdAthirdBthirdC")
```

Answer (score 1):

Update
With help form the awesome #emacs irc channel @freenode.net (Many thanks to wgreenhouse, forcer, paluche, and others)

```
(setq listA '("firstA" "secondA" "thirdA"))
(setq listB '("firstB" "secondB" "thirdB"))
(setq listC '("firstC" "secondC" "thirdC"))

(setq mylist (cl-loop for a in listA
                      for b in listB
                      for c in listC
                      collect (concat a b c)))

(print mylist (current-buffer))
```